# Variable not null on one line, null on the very next

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I'm currently having a problem with an application I'm writing in java via the Netbeans IDE. My code is posted below, along with part of the error message.

```
   public DietUI(DietCntl theCreatingCntl){
   theDietCntl = theCreatingCntl;

   double calories = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.calories;
   double saturatedFat = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.saturatedFat;
   double polyunsaturatedFat = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.polyunsaturatedFat;
   double transFat = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.transFat;
   double totalFat = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.totalFat;
   double cholesterol = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.cholesterol;
   double sodium = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.sodium;
   double potassium = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.potassium;
   double dietaryFiber = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.dietaryFiber;
   double sugar = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.sugar;
   double totalCarbs = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.totalCarbs;
   double protein = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.protein;
   String name = DietCntl.getDietCntl().getDiet().theDiet.
```

//System.out.println is line 30, DietUI.this.etc is line 31.

```
   System.out.println("name in Diet UI: "+name);
   DietUI.this.nameTextField.setText(name);
```

//My problem is that line 31 reads as null. Line 30 does not. Name is instantiated with the correct value one moment and then is null the next.

```
   DietUI.this.cholesterolTextField.setText(String.valueOf(cholesterol));
   DietUI.this.dietaryFiberTextField.setText(String.valueOf(dietaryFiber));
   DietUI.this.caloriesTextField.setText(String.valueOf(calories));
   DietUI.this.polyunsaturatedFatTextField.setText(String.valueOf(polyunsaturatedFat));
   DietUI.this.transFatTextField.setText(String.valueOf(transFat));
   DietUI.this.potassiumTextField.setText(String.valueOf(potassium));
   DietUI.this.saturatedFatTextField.setText(String.valueOf(saturatedFat));
   DietUI.this.sodiumTextField.setText(String.valueOf(sodium));
   DietUI.this.proteinTextField.setText(String.valueOf(protein));
   DietUI.this.sugarTextField.setText(String.valueOf(sugar));
   DietUI.this.totalCarbsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(totalCarbs));
   DietUI.this.totalFatTextField.setText(String.valueOf(totalFat));

}
```

//Below is the output. It contains the System.out.println("name in Diet UI: " +name); as well as part of the error message.

```
name in Diet UI: Name Empty

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at healthbuddy.DietUI.<init>(DietUI.java:31)
at healthbuddy.DietCntl.<init>(DietCntl.java:21)
at healthbuddy.MainMenuCntl.getDietPlannerCntl(MainMenuCntl.java:39)
at healthbuddy.MainMenuUI$DietPlannerButtonListener.actionPerformed(MainMenuUI.java:79)
```

//DietCntl class, included just incase.

```
public class DietCntl {
public static DietCntl theDietCntl;
private Diet theDiet;
public DietCntl(){

}
public DietCntl(int a){
    DietUI theDietUI = new DietUI(this);
}
public static DietCntl getDietCntl(){
    if(theDietCntl == null){
        theDietCntl = new DietCntl();
    }
    return theDietCntl;
}

public Diet getDiet(){
    if(theDiet == null){
        theDiet = new Diet();
    }
    return theDiet;
}

public void getMainMenuCntl(){
    MainMenuCntl theMMCntl = new MainMenuCntl();
```

}
}

Currently I have my Diet object setup such that the name attribute of Diet will be set to "Name Empty" if the Diet object is created with the default constructor. Currently DietUI's constructor extracts the values from Diet and places them in variables. The values of these variables are then placed in textFields for the user to edit.

In DietUI, line 31, my name attribute being read from the Diet class is apparantly null, yet in the line directly above it it displays as the value I expect via System.out.println();. I'm pretty stumped with this. I don't understand how a variable can go to null when the next line of code does nothing to change it's value. I've included my DietCntl class as well, just incase there is something there that is giving me this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Been struggling with this for the better part of a week.

Edit: I'm a bit of an idiot. All my GUI elements are set to initialize in an initComponents method, but I never call the method in my constructor. Thank you kindly stackoverflow.

Comment: Which is line 31? It would really help if you'd cut this down to *just* the relevant code, but also turn it into a complete program. In other words, reduce the program in size until it shows the problem but nothing else.

Comment: (My guess is that you're not initializing `nameTextField`, but we can't tell for sure from the code you've shown us.)

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
System.out.println("name in Diet UI: "+name);
DietUI.this.nameTextField.setText(name);
```

Doesn't do what you think it does.

The first line shows that the `name` variable is not null, but, that's not what's causing your NullPointerException. The problem is that what is null is the `nameTextField` and not the name String. You've likely not initialized any of your GUI components.

for instance, if this is Swing, you must do:

```
// this must be done first
JTextField nameTextField = new JTextField();

// before you can set its text property like so:
nameTextField.setText(name);
```

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> I believe I have done that. I used the Netbeans GUI builder, so it instantiates it for me: nameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField()

Your JVM appears to be telling you otherwise, but don't take my word for it,.... test it! Try:

```
System.out.println("name in Diet UI: "+name);
System.out.println("is nameTextField null?: " + (nameTextField == null));
```

and let us know what is returned.

---

Comment: Nevermind. I'm an idiot. All my GUI stuff is initialized in initComponents(). I never ran initComponents. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @user2966511: your JVM is telling you otherwise. Please see edit to my answer. Try my test code in the location shown and tell us what returns. Edit: more text added to edit. I suspect your entire code is off, perhaps due to over-use of static variable in the DietUI class.

Comment: Actually the `DietUI.this.nameTextField` is just a "normal reference" to an instance field, however the `DietUI.this` is totally unappropiate here, it would be appropiate if you have a non-static inner classes (for example an anonymous inner class), which needs to access a variable of the outer class.

Comment: @skiwi: thanks for the correction. I'll edit my answer accordingly!